# Laravel 4 Email in development environment

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

Mail::pretend() logs only that a `sending mail` was pretended. Is it possible to dump output of the rendered email to a file or log during development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a great option I've started using is https://papercut.codeplex.com/

you set your smtp settings to route to this simple program & it intercepts the emails in an Outlook-like app, as if the email really sent out

Answer (score 0):

If you cache the rendered view in a variable then you can do it, like

```
$renderedView = View::make('email.index', $data); // email(folder)/index(file);
// Now you can dump the output ($renderedView) to a file
File::put('path/to/file', $renderedView)

$data['content'] = $renderedView;
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    // code here
});
```